# Obter objeto dentro de um array que tem o menor valor em uma chave específica em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte *array* de objetos:

```js
const cores = [
  { cor: 'amarelo', peso: 2 },
  { cor: 'amarelo', peso: 3 },
  { cor: 'verde', peso: 7 }
];
```

Meu objetivo é primeiramente filtrá-lo para retornar somente os objetos com a cor amarela, e isso faço com:

```js
const mani = obj.filter(spec => spec.cor === 'amarelo');
```

Após isso, tenho que filtrar esse *array* para que me retorne somente o objeto com o menor peso. No caso, espero receber o seguinte objeto:

```js
{ cor: 'amarelo', peso: 2 }
```

Como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma mais simples é usar um laço `for` para isso. Desse modo, criaremos uma variável para armazenar o objeto que satisfaz as nossas necessidades. A cada iteração verificaremos se o objeto da iteração atual é menor que o objeto de `bigger`. Se for, trocaremos. Algo assim:

```js
const cores = [
  { cor: 'amarelo', peso: 2 },
  { cor: 'amarelo', peso: 3 },
  { cor: 'verde', peso: 7 }
];

const filtered = cores.filter((spec) => spec.cor === 'amarelo');

let bigger; // Criamos uma variável para armazenar o objeto com menor ID.

for (const obj of filtered) {
  // Se `obj` for `null` ou tiver um peso maior que o da iteração
  // atual, iremos trocar pelo objeto atual.
  if (!bigger || obj.peso < bigger.peso) {
    bigger = obj;
  }
}

console.log(bigger);
```

Se você estiver realmente preocupado com performance, o `filter` deixa de ser necessário, uma vez que você pode criar uma condicional um pouco mais complexa no `if` dentro do `for` para isso. Assim:

```
if ((!bigger || obj.peso < bigger.peso) && obj.cor === 'amarelo') {
  /* ... */
}
```

Basicamente, ela verifica se o objeto tem `cor` igual a `amarelo` e se nenhum objeto foi definido ou se o peso do objeto da iteração atual for menor que o já salvo em `bigger`.

```js
const cores = [
  { cor: 'não-amarelo', peso: 0 }, // O menor peso, mas não é amarelo.
  { cor: 'amarelo', peso: 2 },
  { cor: 'amarelo', peso: 3 },
  { cor: 'verde', peso: 7 }
];

let bigger; // Criamos uma variável para armazenar o objeto com menor ID.

for (const obj of cores) {
  if ((!bigger || obj.peso < bigger.peso) && obj.cor === 'amarelo') {
    bigger = obj;
  }
}

console.log(bigger);
```

---

Você pode ainda optar por abordagens mais declarativas usando o `reduce`, já que o `for` é uma abordagem um pouco mais imperativa e "menos pura", já que eventualmente estamos mutando `bigger`.

```js
const cores = [
  { cor: 'não-amarelo', peso: 0 },
  { cor: 'amarelo', peso: 2 },
  { cor: 'amarelo', peso: 3 },
  { cor: 'verde', peso: 7 }
];

const bigger = cores.reduce((saved, current) => {
  return ((!saved || current.peso < saved.peso) && current.cor === 'amarelo') ? current : saved;
}, null);

console.log(bigger);
```

#### Referência

- [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of);
- [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce);

Answer (score 1):

Basta ordernar seu objeto pelo peso e trazer a primeira posição do seu índice:

```
  const mani = cores.filter(spec => (spec.cor === 'amarelo')).sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.peso < b.peso) {
    return -1;
   }
})[0];
```